# Is there any way to get the ID of a Trello card upon creating it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, trello

So, I'm making a Discord Bot which has an integrated Trello board. My aim is for the bot to add a card and then respond with the card's id. I found `Trello.card.getId()` but it's a different language seemingly and returns that getId() isn't a function.

Full code for create function:

```
Trello.card.create(data).then(function(response){
    console.log('Trello card has been added!');
    msg.reply('Trello card has been successfully added!');
    console.log("Card ID:"+Trello.card.getId())
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log('Error: ',error)
  });
```

Using JavaScript.

Comment: Please include some code that allows others to reproduce your problem. How do you create cards? What do you mean by `it's a different language` ?? 

Comment: Added it as an edit.

Comment: What values does the `response` variable have? Could you provide a link to the docs of this API so we can see how it works?

Comment: I expect that the `response` object contains information about the created card. You could use `console.log(response)` to see if the `id` is in there!

Comment: I'll try it, thanks. - Just tested and it works! Do you know how I could get the "id: '[id]'" by itself? - Maybe by removing everything else from the output?

Comment: Update: Managed to get it, see answer below if interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find it! To do this, use the following:

```
    console.log('Trello card has been added!');
    msg.reply('Trello card has been successfully added!');
    msg.reply(response.id);
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log('Error: ',error)
  });
```

Specifically, note "msg.reply(response.id);
Response finds all the information in the card, and .id specifies what to get FROM the response. Hopefully this helps everyone else as much as it helped me. I suggest using `console.log(response)` to see what sort of other things you can get upon creating the card. :)